# single line bash script for wget with retries

Tags: bash

I currently run two commands:

- sleep 180
- wget https://somedomain.com/api/up

So it waits for 3 minutes and then calls api up

I would like to change that so it continuously checks every minute for up to ten minutes until wget returns 200.

so it should be the equivalent of this php function, but in bash. It is important to be a one liner (can be multiple statements separated by ;)

```
foreach(range(1,10) as $i) {
     sleep(60);    
     try {  
         Http::get('https://somedomain.com/api/up');
         break;
     } catch(Exception $e) {
         if($i>=10) throw $e;
     }
}
```

the two things where my bash knowledge fails me:

- how to do the try catch or check for a 200 response code.
- how to get that all into one line/statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop with all the statements separated by `;`

```
for i in {1..10}; do sleep 60; wget 'https://somedomain.com/api/up' && break; done
```

Comment: Thank you. that almost gets me there. I'd only like to exit 0 instead of break and exit 1 instead of the echo:

{ for i in {1..10}; do sleep 60; wget 'https://somedomain.com/api/up' && exit 0; done ; } || exit 1;

however this immediately closes the terminal. Any hint on why that is?

Comment: You don't need `exit 1` since that exits the original shell. The exit status of the loop is the exit status of the last command, so it will be `1` if the loop failed. I added the echo so you can see when this happens, but if you have your own code that tests it, you can get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..5}; do wget -- "$1" && break || sleep 15; done
```